# Adobe Bridge ExtendScript CS5 - Exporting PSD as 300DPI JPEGs

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, bridge

I'm trying to use ExtendScript to "export" PSDs and TIFs from Adobe Bridge CS5 as 300 DPI JPEGs.

I've looked at the BitMap Object and the ExportTo function, but it doesn't appear to accept any parameters other than a JPEG general compression number (0-100).

Right now all of the files are exporting as 72 DPI.

I would also be willing to look at using Bridge to launch an automated Photoshop process if that is something that would work. I've not seen anything showing that it could be used in that way, though.

Comment: DPI is meaningless when talking about digital images. it's only when outputting the image on a printer or screen that DPI comes into play. A 640X480 image is the same at 300dpi as it is at 72 dpi...  just worry about pixel dimensions, that's what matters.

Comment: These files will go into a system that requires all input to be 300DPI. If I attempt to upload these 72DPI images, it will kick back an error. I'm just hoping to automate the process in my existing ExtendScript resources.

Comment: [facepalm].  i really wish analog media folks stopped writing digital interaction... dpi is just a meta setting that has no effect on the image data itself. that said, maybe http://superuser.com/questions/84279/how-to-change-default-photoshop-cs4-resolution-to-96-dpi will set your defaults to something that the upload validation will not reject.

Comment: Yep, it's a pain, but our system interfaces with some companies that include that requirement on all automated image uploads. I had actually tried to set the DPI in Photoshop to see if it would carry over through Bridge exports, but no such luck. I'm thinking my end solution will somehow involve launching Photoshop, passing an array of file URIs and save-to URIs and letting it do the rest.

Comment: photoshop will apply its DPI setting to images saved, including from batch actions. just a simple default example batch resize should leave behind resized images flagged with the default DPI meta.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a Photoshop action...

- Open one of your files in Photoshop
- Locate the Actions panel (window->actions)
- Click the new action icon [image]
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the image size dialog

[image]

- Set the resolution to 300 pixels/inch
- Uncheck Resample
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to save the file somewhere
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> to close (don't save)
- Click the stop button [image] at the bottom of the Actions panel
- Switch to Bridge
- Highlight your files that need to be processed
- Choose Tools->Photoshop->Batch
- Pick the action that you just created from the drpodown
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

And Photoshop will convert all of the files to 300dpi jpgs for you.